# ApolloProvider was not passed a client instance - React Native

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have setup my React Native application with GraphQL. Once I started fresh project and follow the setup of graphql with react native I got this error.

> ApolloProvider was not passed a client instance. Make sure you pass in your client via the client prop

I have followed this [documentation](https://learn.hasura.io/graphql/react-native/apollo-client) with top to bottom.

**apollo.js**

```
import {HttpLink} from 'apollo-link-http';
import {ApolloClient} from 'apollo-client';
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const makeApolloClient = token => {
  // create an apollo link instance, a network interface for apollo client
  const link = new HttpLink({
    uri: `https://learn.hasura.io/graphql`,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
  // create an inmemory cache instance for caching graphql data
  const cache = new InMemoryCache();
  // instantiate apollo client with apollo link instance and cache instance
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache,
  });
  return client;
};
export default makeApolloClient;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import AppContainer from '../routes/Routes';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import {ApolloProvider} from 'react-apollo';
import makeApolloClient from '../apollo/apollo';

console.disableYellowBox = true;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    client: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    // fetch session
    const session = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@todo-graphql:session');
    const sessionObj = JSON.parse(session);
    const {token, id} = sessionObj;
    // make apollo client with this session token
    const client = makeApolloClient(token);
    // start emitting events saying that the useri s online
    this.setState({client});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client={this.state.client}>
        <AppContainer />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Error**

[image]

```
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.4",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.16",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
"react-native": "0.61.3",
```

Answer (score 1):

Render gets called before componentDidMount. Because of this, client instance will be null during the first render. This causes the error. Modify your render method as

```
render() {
  if(!this.state.client) {
    return <Text>Loading</Text>
  }
  return (
      <ApolloProvider client={this.state.client}>
        <AppContainer />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time ! But your answer gives me only Loading Text. It won't return the AppContainer. Same as this I added Activity Indicator. It only loading but not returning the App