# Cannot read property 'ApolloProvider' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, apollo-client

I am trying to compile my React Native application version `0.64.0`. Everything was ok after migration from javascript to typescript, but suddently I got this problem:

[Screenshot to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta7zX.png)

I tryied delete node modules and yarn again, and I didn't get any success compilation.

I also I have this error on console:

[Error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEcMr.png)

I don't know if I have to install anything else, please help me.

This is my apollo client version:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.3.13",
```

Comment: The error you're seeing seems very similar to the issue seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58637132/apolloprovider-was-not-passed-a-client-instance-react-native). Have you verified the client props is successfully being sent and is render after componentDidMount?